# How to configure Varnish in an API-platform project? [Response size limit issue]

Tags: api, symfony, varnish, api-platform.com

Sometimes in my preproduction and production environment, the varnish container send me this error:

```
Error (null) Backend fetch failed
Backend fetch failed

Guru Meditation:
XID: (null)
```

This is due to the size of the body response.

So I did implement this test in my Postman test collection:

```
pm.test("Size is under 3Ko", function () {
    pm.expect(pm.response.responseSize).to.be.below(3000);
});
```

To be sure that this error does not not appear again.

But I am wondering how can I configure it properly to accept a reasonable size of response?

This my configuration:

> Api Platform 2.5.1
>   VCL 4.0

Comment: What do you mean by "average size"? Isn't that heavily dependent on each project?

Comment: I mean if you calculate the size of the response of ten API calls in your project, What would be the average of the size of the response ? lower than 10Ko, bigger ?

Comment: What's the point in asking this? Is there any hint that there might be any limitation?

Comment: I am asking that to compare practices, may be we have too bigger response and this is why varnish is set by default with this small limitation. We tried to augment varnish limits but without success. but you're right, this is not a good question after all.

Comment: yes you're right @yivi this is why i change my post :)

Answer (score 0):

Varnish documentation states that the default maximum size of an HTTP response is **32 KB**.
You can tune this by setting the [http_resp_size](https://varnish-cache.org/docs/6.0/reference/varnishd.html#http-resp-size) runtime parameter.

Here's an example of an increased `http_resp_size` value:

`varnishd -p http_resp_size=1M`

If that doesn't help, please share the `varnishlog` output for that specific page, as well as the associated `VCL` code.

If you're unsure whether or not your `http_resp_size` was set to the correct value, you can run the following command on your Varnish server:

```
    $ varnishadm param.show http_resp_size
```

Hope this helps.